# DefaultDataSource.Factory not working in exoployer android Required: DataSource.Factory Found: String?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am developing spotify like android app and I am following tutorial in the code

teacher using `DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "Spotify Application"))` but as DefaultDataSourceFactory depreciated in exoplayer  I am using  in following way  `DefaultDataSource.Factory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "Spotify Application"))` but I am getting following mismatch Type mismatch.
Required:
DataSource.Factory
Found:
String

[image: error mismatch]

I want to know what I am doing wrong in my code
below tutorial code which is depreciated

[image: tutorial code]